# What is the meaning of the "...........vidmahe....Dhimahi....prachodayat" formula?

Tags: mantras, translation-request, sanskrit

Here is an example I took from another post here:

> bhaskaraya vidmahe mahaddyutikaraya dhimahi |
>  tanno adityyah pracodayat

There are lots of variants of this formula.  What is the context in which this formula is used and what does it mean?

Comment: these are parts of gayatri mantras of different deities. You would get the main Gayatri which is for Sabitur or Sun or the Supreme Creator and different gayatris of different vedic and tantrik deities

Comment: Gayatri means the mantra singing or chanting which one is freed from hindrances obstacles and dangers

Comment: Bhaskara is another name of Surya Deva. That is a Gayatri mantra for worshipping the Sun.

Answer (score 2):

**Dhimahi:-** This word is derived from *√dhi* which means *to worship* or *meditate*. From [V.S. Apte Dictionary;](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/apte_query.py?qs=%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%83&searchhws=yes)
[image]

**Vidmahe:-** It is derived from *√vid* which means *to know* or *understand*. [Source](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/apte_query.py?qs=%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%83&searchhws=yes)
[image]

**Prachodyat:-** It is derived from *√pracud* which means *to inspire*.

[image]

Maharishi Dayananda translated the word *dhimahi* and *prachodyat* as mentioned above in Gayatri mantra.

[image]

The word to word translation of the mantra you gave in question is given [here.](https://livingsanskrit.com/aditya-gayatri-mantra/)

Comment: Good answer. You might want to remove the blpg link you have given in the end because blogs aren't valid, plus that site is defunct and under repair currently. Even without the blog the answer is good, imo.